# class net.minecraft.client.entity.player.ClientPlayerEntity cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.entity.player.ServerPlayerEntity

Tags: java, user-interface, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a mod on 1.16.5, but when I created a gui for a tile entity according to the tutorial and ran minecraft to test the gui, minecraft crashed and wrote me that
class net.minecraft.client.entity.player.ClientPlayerEntity cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.entity.player.ServerPlayerEntity however the author of the tutorial didn't get this error.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public ActionResultType use(BlockState p_225533_1_, World worldIn, BlockPos pos,
            PlayerEntity player, Hand p_225533_5_, BlockRayTraceResult p_225533_6_) {
        if(worldIn.isClientSide()) {
            TileEntity te = worldIn.getBlockEntity(pos);
            if(te instanceof DisplayCaseTileEntity) {
                NetworkHooks.openGui((ServerPlayerEntity) player, (DisplayCaseTileEntity) te, pos); // the problem in this line
            }
        }
        return super.use(p_225533_1_, worldIn, pos, player, p_225533_5_, p_225533_6_);
    }
```

i tried to change ServerPlayerEntity to PlayerEntity but openGui() works only with ServerPlayerEntity

Comment: @user16320675 I tried to set PlayerEntity instead of ServerPlayerEntity but it is underlined as an error because PlayerEntity is not applicable for openGui and it is suggested to add cast argument ServerPlayerEntity

Comment: SO maybe it's not the good way to open an inventory? Did you checked for [this](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/latest/gui/menus/#opening-a-menu) or [this](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/1431942-forge-item-client-side-gui-not-possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about where this code is executed... (Almost) every code in this project is executed once by the server and once by the client! You've already "sorted it out" with the line:

```
if(worldIn.isClientSide()) {
```

but when the client executes the code, it of course only gives you an object of the class ClientPlayerEntity!
The only thing wrong with your code is that you forgot an exclamation mark to negate the IF statement.

```
if(!worldIn.isClientSide()) {
```

the method

```
NetworkHooks.openGui(...);
```

can only be executed by the server...
If you have methods in the future that should only be executed by the server, use:

```
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.OnlyIn;

public class OnlyForServer {
    @OnlyIn(Dist.DEDICATED_SERVER)
    public void method() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And you can ofcourse use as well:

```
@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT);
```

if you only want it to be activated by the client!